# Why are styles overwritten if I apply more styles to text in separate methods?

Tags: c#, scintilla

I'm programming my custom styles for my disassembler. Unfortunately, it seems like it always overwrites the style to the latest characters and the other styles are lost. Here my code which calls my styling:

```
        if (Base)
        {
            ITypeBase Instr = new ITypeBase();
            Instr = BaseTypeSplit(bits, Instr);

            Disassemble._dis.updateOP(CheckOpcode(Instr.opcode) + " ");
            Disassemble._dis.updateREG(CheckReg(Instr.rt));
            Disassemble._dis.updateCOMMA(", ");
            Disassemble._dis.updateIMM(CheckImm(Instr.imm));
            Disassemble._dis.updateREGB("(" + CheckReg(Instr.@base) + ")");
        }
```

Yes, my main code calls the scintilla Box from another class. I use my constructor from the other class (`_dis = this;`) to access it.

And here my functions which do the styling:

```
    public Disassemble()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dis = this;
     }

    public static Disassemble _dis;


    public void updateOP(string message)
    {
        int length = scintilla1.TextLength; 
        int length2 = message.Length; 
        int sum = length + length2; 

        scintilla1.Styles[1].Font = new Font("Arial", 25, FontStyle.Bold);
        scintilla1.Styles[1].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 0);
        scintilla1.Text += message;

        int n = length;

        while (length < sum)
        {
            scintilla1.GetRange(n).SetStyle(1);
            n = length + 1;
            length += 1;
        }
    }

    public void updateREG(string message)
    {
        int length = scintilla1.TextLength; 
        int length2 = message.Length;
        int sum = length + length2; 

        scintilla1.Styles[2].Font = new Font("Arial", 25, FontStyle.Bold);
        scintilla1.Styles[2].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0);
        scintilla1.Text += message;

        int n = length;

        while (length < sum)
        {
            scintilla1.GetRange(n).SetStyle(2);
            n = length + 1;
            length += 1;
        }
    }

    public void updateREGB(string message)
    {
        int length = scintilla1.TextLength; 
        int length2 = message.Length; 
        int sum = length + length2; 

        scintilla1.Styles[5].Font = new Font("Arial", 25, FontStyle.Bold);
        scintilla1.Styles[5].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(172, 172, 172);
        scintilla1.Text += message;

        int n = length;

        while (length < sum)
        {
            scintilla1.GetRange(n).SetStyle(5);
            n = length + 1;
            length += 1;
        }
    }

    public void updateCOMMA(string message)
    {
        int length = scintilla1.TextLength;
        int length2 = message.Length;
        int sum = length + length2;

        scintilla1.Styles[3].Font = new Font("Arial", 25, FontStyle.Bold);
        scintilla1.Styles[3].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
        scintilla1.Text += message;

        int n = length;

        while (length < sum)
        {
            scintilla1.GetRange(n).SetStyle(3);
            n = length + 1;
            length += 1;
        }
    }

    public void updateIMM(string message)
    {
        int length = scintilla1.TextLength;
        int length2 = message.Length;
        int sum = length + length2;

        scintilla1.Styles[4].Font = new Font("Arial", 25, FontStyle.Bold);
        scintilla1.Styles[4].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255);
        scintilla1.Text += message;

        int n = length;

        while (length < sum)
        {
            scintilla1.GetRange(n).SetStyle(4);
            n = length + 1;
            length += 1;
        }
    }
```

And this is what I get, always:

[image]

As you see, it only styles the latest characters and the other styled characters lose their styling and are overwritten.

I've tried some (horrible) ways, but they also didn't result in what I wanted. Does someone have an idea what could be the cause of this? For additional information, I use Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, found my own solution. Instead of putting it into separate methods, I decided to put it into one and put all my while loops in there. This is my result and it worked successfully:

```
    public void updateBase(string opcode, string rt, string comma, string imm, string @base)
    {
        int tlen = scintilla1.TextLength; // 12
        int olen = opcode.Length;
        int rlen = rt.Length;
        int clen = comma.Length;
        int ilen = imm.Length;
        int blen = @base.Length;
        int n = 0;

        scintilla1.Text += opcode;
        scintilla1.Text += rt;
        scintilla1.Text += comma;
        scintilla1.Text += imm;
        scintilla1.Text += @base;

        int sumt = tlen + olen;

        while (tlen < sumt)
        {
            n = tlen - 1;
            tlen += 1;
            scintilla1.GetRange(n).SetStyle(1);
        }

        sumt = tlen + rlen;

        while (tlen < sumt)
        {
            n = tlen /*+ 1*/;
            tlen += 1;
            scintilla1.GetRange(n).SetStyle(2);
        }

        sumt = tlen + clen;

        while (tlen < sumt)
        {
            n = tlen /*+ 1*/;
            tlen += 1;
            scintilla1.GetRange(n).SetStyle(3);
        }

        sumt = tlen + ilen;

        while (tlen < sumt)
        {
            n = tlen /*+ 1*/;
            tlen += 1;
            scintilla1.GetRange(n).SetStyle(4);
        }

        sumt = tlen + blen;

        while (tlen < sumt)
        {
            n = tlen /*+ 1*/;
            tlen += 1;
            scintilla1.GetRange(n).SetStyle(5);
        }

    }
```

And here the result:

[image: result]